# Why does this interchanging of derivative and sum work?

Tags: statistics, derivatives, summation

I'm reading a stats book and, for a geometric distrubution ($E[Y]=p \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}yq^{y-1})$ it makes the claim that since

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dq}(q^y)=yq^{y-1}$

hence

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dq}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty} q^y = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} yq^{y-1}$

My question: how is this valid? Is it generally the case that $(\sum f_n(x))' = \sum f_n'(x)$ or do some conditions have to hold for this to be the case?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) for a discussion of this operation.

Comment: Because the derivative is a linear operation.

Comment: Is this possibly a duplicate of this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44373/sense-of-the-linearity-of-the-derivative

Answer (score 3):

Power series can always be differentiated term-by-term on the interior of their interval of convergence.

Comment: Yes, $(\sum f_n(x))' = \sum f_n'(x)$ is valid for power series on the interior of the interval of convergence.  Which is the best answer for the question.  Other cases where $(\sum f_n(x))' = \sum f_n'(x)$ holds: the series on the right converges uniformly; $f'_n(x) \ge 0$ for all $n,x$.  (Another Theorem of Fubini)

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the proof of this, at least the ones I've seen, appeal to  the theorem mentioned in the Wiki article linked above.

Comment: There is a pretty standard direct computational argument, too, as in http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/abel_thm_on_ps.pdf  And I'd also assert that nearly always term-wise differentiation is perfectly fine _if_ interpreted properly. Especially when it is _necessary_ to differentiate termwise for a meaningful argument to continue, probably the real question is just the proper interpretation, not whether or not it "can" be done: it _must_ be done, etc. :)